# HTML / PHP first dropdown changes second dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've looked through this site and think I have the right code to change a second dropdown value based on the first dropdown. Here is the code below, but for some reason it still won't work for me.

Here's the code on my **main page**:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
?>

<select id="projectSelector" name="projectSelector">
<option selected value="base">--Select an option--</option>

<?php
$sqlOptions = "SELECT name from driver WHERE loginID='$loginID'"; 
$resultOptions = mysql_query($sqlOptions); 
while($opt = mysql_fetch_array($resultOptions)) 
{ 
   echo '<option value="'.$opt['name'].'">'.$opt['name'].'</option>'; 
} 

?>
</select>

<select id="customerSelector">
<option>--Select an Option--</option>
</select>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">    <\/script>')</script>
 <script>


 $(function() 
 {
 $("#projectSelector").change(function() 
 {
 $("#customerSelector").load("getter.php?project_id=" + $("#projectSelector").val());
 });
 });    
 </script>
```

And then in my **getter.php** file this is the code I have:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$sProjectId = $_GET['project_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE driver='$sProjectId'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['unitID'].'">'.$row['unitID'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

So the first dropdown works perfectly. It connects to the msyql database and gives out a list of all available choices. When I make the first choice, the second drop down doesn't show anything. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Use an error_log to determine what the script is getting, then run the query manually and see what you get. Also, the MySQL_* functions are now depreciated in the latest version of PHP, you could consider upgrading to mySQLi or PDO (Google).

Comment: First try to run "getter.php?project_id={id}" directly on browser and see what its returning.

Comment: I tried your code without the database part and with certain conditions for `project_id` , it works okay so you should probably check on the query.

Comment: do you really need to escape `<\/script>`?

Comment: you try to write a `<script>` block into another `<script>` block.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, until someone suggested I use this tutorial attached.

http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I think You have problem in query of getter.php file
Your query wher clause is
 **where driver='$sProjectId'**

 which means select where driver value is $sProjectId.
you have to use,like this
**$query = "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE driver='".$sProjectId."'";**
Now it will take the driver value which is equal to $sProjectId variable.
Hope it may help you.